# How to find location with Geolocation?

Tags: jquery, html, geolocation

I'm trying to find the location of my computer using Geolocation, and I'm having a tough time figuring it out. I wanted it connected to an event listener that when the paragraph is clicked, it runs.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <p id="para1">
    Click to find location
    </p>
```

And here's my script:

```
    //Global variables

 var elMap = document.getElementById("para1");
 var msg = 'Sorry, we were unable to get your location';

if (Modernizr.geolocation) {                                
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);  
elMap.textContent = 'Checking location...';               
} else {                                                    
elMap.textContent = msg;                                  
}

   //Event listeners

document.getElementById("para1").addEventListener("click", geoAPI);

function geoAPI() {


function success(position) {                                
 msg = '<h3>Longitude:<br>';                               
 msg += position.coords.longitude + '</h3>';               
 msg += '<h3>Latitude:<br>';                               
 msg += position.coords.latitude + '</h3>';                
  elMap.innerHTML = msg;                                    
}

function fail(msg) {                                        
 elMap.textContent = msg;                                  
 console.log(msg.code);                                    
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I was close, it should be

```
    //Global variables

var elMap = document.getElementById("para1");
var msg = 'Sorry, we were unable to get your location';

function success(position) {                                
  msg = '<h3>Longitude:<br>';                               
  msg += position.coords.longitude + '</h3>';               
  msg += '<h3>Latitude:<br>';                               
  msg += position.coords.latitude + '</h3>';                
  elMap.innerHTML = msg;                                    
}

function fail(msg) {                                        
  elMap.textContent = msg;                                  
  console.log(msg.code);                                    
}

//Event listeners





 function geoAPI() {

    if (Modernizr.geolocation) {                                
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);  
  elMap.textContent = 'Checking location...';               
}     else {                                                    
  elMap.textContent = msg;                                  
}

}

elMap.addEventListener('click', geoAPI);
```